# Display emogi icon in unichar with string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, emoji, unichar

In my application i want to display emoji icon with string but its giving me syntax error.

It's displays below string successfully

```
unichar character = 0xE116;
self.uniCharStr =[NSString stringWithCharacters:&character length:1];
```

But its giving syntax error while i use value as following.

```
unichar character = &#x1f4a1
self.uniCharStr =[NSString stringWithCharacters:&character length:1];
```

I have get this values from emoji icon list from this [link](http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/).

Can anyone please guide me where i m wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using an HTML encode HEX string, you will need to used an Unicde hex value in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\U0001F4A1` instead of  `&#x1f4a1`

You should replace `&#x` with`U000` also dont forget to add an escape sequence.

Edit :

To display the emoji in a label, I use the following code.

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\U0001f4a1"];
```

Comment: Hi,still getting syntax error, still is there anything missing ?

Comment: ITs showing error like expected expression, i think i m wrong somewhere but not getting where. i have used like this.       unichar character;
character =\U0001F4A1;
self.uniCharStr =
[NSString stringWithCharacters:&character length:1];

Comment: Edited my answer, I think you can construct your string according to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this will help you.

```
NSString *emojiStr  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", @"0xE116"];
```

Comment: above is already working well, getting error for this <unichar character = &#x1f4a1>

Comment: Edited my answer. Please try that.

Comment: Its direct print as a string like (0xE116)